# Entity framework with plugins

Tags: c#, entity-framework, plugins

**What I'm currently doing**
I have a plugin system. Each plugin has to implement an interface and gets loaded and initialized by the main application. On my server I have a MySql database which is used to store data from these plugins (each plugin can have multiple, individual tables).

I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore to connect and interact with my database.

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder.UseMySql(ConnectionString);
}
```

As written above, each fragment can have its own table (the main application doesn't know `NoteDatabaseContext`).

```
public class NoteDatabaseContext : DatabaseContext
{
    public DbSet<Note> Note { get; set; }
}
```

**What I want to archive**
I want to create one `DatabaseContext` for each plugin. The `DatabaseContext` should be passed to the plugin (e.g. by it's constructor) and should NOT contain the connection string. The plugin developer should be able to add his table. How can I archive this?